# How to set a custom href into a button when onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL

`http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/assignment?x=1&y=2&z=3`

I have 2 btns

[image]

I'm not sure how would I bind those 2 btn to the correct URL.

If the `Remediation` is clicked, I want to set the href to

`http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/remediation?x=1&y=2&z=3`

The only different is the 4th segment, the rest stay the same.

Any helps / suggestions on them will be much appreciated !

I guess - I might have to :

- grab the whole URL
- re-construct the newURL, store it in a variable
- bind that newURL to my btn.

I hope I'm in the right track for this. 
Let me know if you guys, notice something.

Comment: ngHref is useful for building/modifying href strings.

Comment: I work on other people project, and the only framework that I'm allow to use is jQuery. I wish Angular is allow.

Comment: Sorry for some reason Stackoverflow popped this into my AngularJS feed.

Comment: did you mean, you have to bind the urls on run-time?

Comment: yes. have to bind the urls on run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can change the URL to what ever you like.
I am using Replace fucntion to change the URL on the fly

```
var url='http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/assignment?x=1&y=2&z=3'

$('button1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', url);
});
$('button2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', url.replace('assignment','remediation');
});
```

Comment: Is your suggestion is easy to expand ? just curious.

Comment: Sure. How do you want to be expanded?

Comment: I guess that good enough for me. Thank for the helps. The reward is your.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(/*remediation button selector*/).click(function() {
    $(/*assignment performance button selector*/).attr('href', 'http://localhost:8080/BIM/teacher/reports/section-exercise/remediation?x=1&y=2&z=3');
});
```

I'm not sure if you meant you want the Remediation button to change the href for the first button, or if you want them to just have different hrefs; if it's the latter, they can just have the different hrefs directly in the HTML, no JS needed.

Comment: The part after `?` will be changing. I'm not sure if I should do it your way.

Answer (score 1):

Aminas answer is good, but in case the first URL isn't always the same I would recommend this function (using Regex) to change only the file name of an URL:

```
function changeFileName(strURL, strNewName) {
    return strURL.replace(/[^\/?]*(?=\?|$)/, strNewName);
}
```

This (a) works no matter what the original file name was, and (b) won't cause problem if the path contains the file name.